# Use ajax to send image file to python (flask)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have an image on my website being updated every 5 seconds (using PubNub and a Raspberry Pi. I use JavaScript to update the image source). This works fine. My problem is I am trying to use Ajax to send the source file to python (flask) and store that file in a MySQL database. Then I want to display the file name on the website. I am new to java script/ ajax.

Here is my java script:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        $('img#imageid').bind( function() {
            $.getJSON('/_button', {
                proglang: document.getElementById('imageid').src,
            }, function(data) {
                $("#buttonState").text(data.result);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The **img#imageid** is the id of the current image and the **#buttonstate** is where i would like to have the image file name displayed

Here is my html:

```
<img id="imageid" src="http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2015/12/google-amp-fast-speed-travel-ss-1920-800x450.jpg">
<form>
    <p>The button is <span id="buttonState"></span></p>
    <br>
</form>
```

I do not want to use GET or POST. I would like to to automatically send to the python file every time the image source changes.

Here is my Flask view:

```
@app.route("/_button")
def _button():
    try:
        lang = request.args.get('proglang')
        c.execute ("""UPDATE pictures SET file_name=%s WHERE user_id=%s""",
                                       (str(lang), str(session['user_id'])))
        return jsonify(buttonState=lang)
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template("500.html", error = str(e))
```

Comment: Why *not* just POST the image? You could use websockets for this, but its a bit more involved to get setup and working.